Riesz projection has a continuous extension to $L^{p}$ only for $1< p< \infty$
Let $n \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$. We usually call the function of the form $p(t) = \sum_{k = -n}^{n}\alpha_{k}t^{k}$, where $\alpha_{k} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t \in \mathbb{T}$, a trigonometric polynomial of order n. For convenience we denote by $\mathcal{P}$ the space of trigonometric polynomials. It is clear that $\mathcal{P} \subset L^{P}(\mathbb{T})$. On $\mathcal{P}$, we define the Riesz projection given by
$$P: \sum_{k=-n}^{n}\alpha_{k}t^{k} \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}t^{k}$$.
It turns out that the Riesz projection extends to a bounded linear operator on $L^{p}(\mathbb{T})$ if and only if $1 < p < \infty$. I am not sure why is this true. Can someone help me on this?
Thanks

What is commonly referred to as a trig polynomial is $p(e^{2\pi i})$, with $p$ as you have defined. Is this what you mean?

Are you asking why the Riesz transform is bounded for $ 1<p<\infty$ or why it is unbounded on $L^1$ ? Or both?

Yes, I am guessing that for $L^{1} or L^{\infty}$, there exists some function in the domain for which $P$ is unbounded.

For $0<r<1$ and $|\theta|<\pi$ let
$$f_r(\theta )=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}$$ Then
$$f_r(\theta)={1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$$ The function $f_r$ is called the Poisson kernel. As $f_r\ge 0$ we have $\|f_r\|_1={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f_r(\theta)\,d\theta=1.$
On the other hand $$Pf_r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{in\theta}={1\over 1-re^{i\theta}}$$
We have $$|1-re^{i\theta}|\le 1-r+r|1-e^{i\theta}|\\ =1-r+2r|\sin(\theta/2)|\\ \le 1-r+r|\theta|$$
Thus $$\|Pf_r\|_1 \ge {1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi {1\over 1-r + r\theta}\,d\theta \\ =\left. {1\over 2\pi r}\log (1-r+r\theta)\right\vert _{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}\\ = {1\over2\pi r}[\log(1-r+r\pi)-\log (1-r)]$$
Therefore $\lim_{r\to 1^-}\|Pf_r\|_1=\infty.$
